# HighCharts: enviar un array a un dynamic update Chart

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente Grafica, pero quisiera graficar dos curvas, pero no se como enviarle la otra curva, en comentario esta lo que he intentado, alguien sabe como?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ge0rfbnh/
```

> Actualizo:

He podido hacerlo, sin embargo la segunda curva no avanza como la primera

```
http://jsfiddle.net/0qfjvguy/
```

Comment: Si, perfecto, muchas, gracias sin embargo, que pena molestarte, tu sabrias de calusalidad colocarle un scroll a esa grafica?, muchisimas gracias de antemano y tambn gracias por la solucion

Comment: Muchas gracias todo ha sido perfecto, te he marcado como respuesta correcta, aunque tengo una pequeña ultima duda mas, sabes como desactivar la animacion, la curva azul la tiene, la negra no, gracias

Comment: animation: false dentro de la serie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te muestro un ejemplo practico de dos series si vez la variable puedes modificarla:

> https://jsfiddle.net/5httzpLs

Un ejemplo usando highStock

> https://jsfiddle.net/vvpf4mtw/